# parsing wordpress api json response in react using .map

Tags: json, reactjs, wordpress

im trying to parse the normal posts endpoint on wordpres using react JS. However im getting this error when i try and do a .map iteration on the response object

**Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {rendered, protected}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

heres the function within the component to read posts and display them

```
 getPosts(){
      var th = this;
      var url = "http://localhost/portal/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";

        axios.get(url,{}).then(function(response){
            var obj =response.data;
            console.info(obj);
            th.setState({
                blogPosts: obj
            });
        },this)

      console.log(th.state.blogPosts)
  }
```

heres the rendering within the render() function.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="ui items">
            {


            this.state.blogPosts.map((post,index)=>

                <div className="item">
                    <div className="ui tiny image">
                        <img src="https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="content">
                        <a className="header">{post.title}</a>
                        <div className="meta">{post.excerpt}</div>
                        <div className="description">
                            {post.content}
                        </div>
                        <div className="extra">{post.link}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
  }
```

heres is the json to be parsed

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"date": "2020-03-03T10:46:56",
"date_gmt": "2020-03-03T10:46:56",
"guid": {
"rendered": "http://localhost/coaching-portal/blog/?p=1"
},
"modified": "2020-03-03T10:46:56",
"modified_gmt": "2020-03-03T10:46:56",
"slug": "hello-world",
"status": "publish",
"type": "post",
"link": "http://localhost/coaching-portal/blog/2020/03/03/hello-world/",
"title": {
"rendered": "Hello world!"
},
"content": {
"rendered": "\n<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!</p>\n",
"protected": false
},
"excerpt": {
"rendered": "<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!</p>\n",
"protected": false
},
"author": 1,
"featured_media": 0,
"comment_status": "open",
"ping_status": "open",
"sticky": false,
"template": "",
"format": "standard",
"meta": [],
"categories": [
1
],
"tags": [],
"_links": {}
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all of the items you're rendering in JSX are primitives and not objects when using ReactJS.

I can also see title, excerpt, content are objects. Try may be formatting the object, and display necessary fields

For Example

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="ui items">
            {
            this.state.blogPosts.map((post,index)=>
                <div className="item">
                    <div className="ui tiny image">
                        <img src="https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="content">
                        <a className="header">{post.title.rendered}</a>
                        <div className="meta">{post.excerpt.rendered}</div>
                        <div className="description">
                            {post.content.rendered}
                        </div>
                        <div className="extra">{post.link}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a problem here:
`<div className="meta">{post.excerpt}</div>`

post.expcerpt looks like this

```
excerpt:{
"rendered": "\n<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!</p>\n",
"protected": false",
}
```

Try using `<div className="meta">{post.excerpt.rendered}</div>` instead if you want to get the text from that object.

It looks to be a similar case with your 
`<a className="header">{post.title}</a>`